# How to use marker area learn

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, augmented-reality, aframe

Right now I'm working with Three.js , Aframe and AR.js .
I'm following Jerome's example :

https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/three.js/examples/multi-markers/examples/player.html

I've included his library in my project sample and I'm trying to figure out why this happens :

When I'm on the player.html page , everything's working , the console doesn't display any error , just a warning :

```
 stop profile.trackingBackend() obsolete function. use .trackingMethod instead
```

(But I don't think this is causing the problem)
And then , when I click to scan the markers , the button works , the function behind executes , I get redirected to the learner.html webpage , but all import scripts are getting 400 error code and aren't loaded on the website so nothing's working.

What I did : I've checked the scripts via online tools , line by line , copy paste try.They're the same , when I say the same I mean the learner.html page has 3 less scripts imported than the player.html , the common scripts syntax is the same on both pages.

What I noticed : If I try to access the webpage without the options in the URL the page is perfectly working ... well , the page is giving me some output about the missins options but the scripts are loaded , but I need the options :(

The problem with the scripts imports I think it's caused by that object included in the URL webpage , weird thing because it has some other things added in the player webpage as well and it's working.

I'm using NodeJS v4.2.6 & NPM v3.5.2 & Express v4.16.4
This is the way how I handle the requests for these 2 page in NodeJS:

```
app.get('/multiMarkers4', function (req, res) {
  res.render( pathView + 'player.ejs', { pageName:"player", errorMsg:"" });
});

app.get('/learner', function (req, res) {
  res.render( pathView + 'learner.ejs', { pageName:"learner", errorMsg:"" });
});
```

Yes, I've changed the files from html to ejs and moved them into the /views ( only these 2 learner.ejs and player.ejs )
For scripts I've created some specific paths in Node :

```
app.use('/three', express.static(__dirname + '/three.js'));
```

The learner.ejs and player.ejs webpages have pretty much the same code as they have in the Jerome's GitHub repository , the only modified thing are the import scripts :

This is in player.ejs and it's working

```
<!-- three.js library -->
<script src='/three/examples/vendor/three.js/build/three.js'></script>
<script src='/three/examples/vendor/three.js/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js'></script>

<!-- jsartookit -->
<script src='/three/vendor/jsartoolkit5/build/artoolkit.min.js'></script>
<script src='/three/vendor/jsartoolkit5/js/artoolkit.api.js'></script>

<!-- aruco -->
<script src='/three/vendor/js-aruco/src/svd.js'></script>
<script src='/three/vendor/js-aruco/src/posit1.js'></script>
<script src='/three/vendor/js-aruco/src/cv.js'></script>
<script src='/three/vendor/js-aruco/src/aruco.js'></script>
<script src='/three/src/threex/threex-aruco/threex-arucocontext.js'></script>
<script src='/three/src/threex/threex-aruco/threex-arucodebug.js'></script>

<!-- include threex.artoolkit -->
<script src='/three/src/threex/threex-artoolkitsource.js'></script>
<script src='/three/src/threex/threex-artoolkitcontext.js'></script>
<script src='/three/src/threex/threex-artoolkitprofile.js'></script>
<script src='/three/src/threex/threex-arbasecontrols.js'></script>
<script src='/three/src/threex/threex-armarkercontrols.js'></script>
<script src='/three/src/threex/threex-armarkerhelper.js'></script>
<script src='/three/src/threex/threex-arsmoothedcontrols.js'></script>
<script>THREEx.ArToolkitContext.baseURL = '';</script>

<script src='/three/examples/multi-markers/threex-armultimarkerutils.js'></script>
<script src='/three/examples/multi-markers/threex-armultimarkercontrols.js'></script>
<script src='/three/examples/multi-markers/threex-armultimarkerlearning.js'></script>

<script src='/three/examples/multi-markers/examples/threex-screenasportal/threex-screenasportal.js'></script>
<script>THREEx.ScreenAsPortal.baseURL = 'threex-screenasportal/';</script>
```

When I'm on player.ejs page the URL is :

```
https://x.y.z/multiMarkers4#%7B"trackingBackend"%3A"artoolkit"%7D
```

When I'm on player.ejs page the console log in devTools is :

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer 86
threex-artoolkitprofile.js:145 stop profile.trackingBackend() obsolete function. use .trackingMethod instead
ARjs.Profile.trackingBackend @ threex-artoolkitprofile.js:145(This is that warning,the rest of the output is just simple output)
artoolkit.min.js:1 Allocated videoFrameSize 1228800
artoolkit.min.js:1 Pattern detection mode set to 1.
artoolkit.min.js:1 Pattern ratio size set to 0.500000.
```

This is in learner.ejs and it's working WITHOUT THE OPTIONS IN URL :

```
<!-- three.js library -->
<script src='/three/examples/vendor/three.js/build/three.js'></script>
<script src='/three/examples/vendor/three.js/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js'></script>

<!-- jsartookit -->
<script src='/three/vendor/jsartoolkit5/build/artoolkit.min.js'></script>
<script src='/three/vendor/jsartoolkit5/js/artoolkit.api.js'></script>

<!-- aruco -->
<script src='/three/vendor/js-aruco/src/svd.js'></script>
<script src='/three/vendor/js-aruco/src/posit1.js'></script>
<script src='/three/vendor/js-aruco/src/cv.js'></script>
<script src='/three/vendor/js-aruco/src/aruco.js'></script>
<script src='/three/src/threex/threex-aruco/threex-arucocontext.js'></script>
<script src='/three/src/threex/threex-aruco/threex-arucodebug.js'></script>

<!-- include threex.artoolkit -->
<script src='/three/src/threex/threex-artoolkitsource.js'></script>
<script src='/three/src/threex/threex-artoolkitcontext.js'></script>
<script src='/three/src/threex/threex-artoolkitprofile.js'></script>
<script src='/three/src/threex/threex-arbasecontrols.js'></script>
<script src='/three/src/threex/threex-armarkercontrols.js'></script>
<script src='/three/src/threex/threex-armarkerhelper.js'></script>
<script src='/three/src/threex/threex-arsmoothedcontrols.js'></script>
<script>THREEx.ArToolkitContext.baseURL = '';</script>

<script src='/three/examples/multi-markers/threex-armultimarkerutils.js'></script>
<script src='/three/examples/multi-markers/threex-armultimarkercontrols.js'></script>
<script src='/three/examples/multi-markers/threex-armultimarkerlearning.js'></script>
```

When I'm on learner.ejs page the URL is :

```
https://x.y.z/learner?%7B"backURL"%3A"https%3A%2F%2Fx.y.z%2FmultiMarkers4%23%257B%2522trackingBackend%2522%253A%2522artoolkit%2522%257D"%2C"trackingBackend"%3A"artoolkit"%2C"markersControlsParameters"%3A%5B%7B"type"%3A"pattern"%2C"patternUrl"%3A"https%3A%2F%2Fx.y.z%2FmultiMarkers4patts%2Fhiro.patt"%7D%2C%7B"type"%3A"pattern"%2C"patternUrl"%3A"https%3A%2F%2Fx.y.z%2FmultiMarkers4patts%2Fkanji.patt"%7D%2C%7B"type"%3A"pattern"%2C"patternUrl"%3A"https%3A%2F%2Fx.y.z%2FmultiMarkers4patts%2Fa.patt"%7D%2C%7B"type"%3A"pattern"%2C"patternUrl"%3A"https%3A%2F%2Fx.y.z%2FmultiMarkers4patts%2Fb.patt"%7D%2C%7B"type"%3A"pattern"%2C"patternUrl"%3A"https%3A%2F%2Fx.y.z%2FmultiMarkers4patts%2Fc.patt"%7D%2C%7B"type"%3A"pattern"%2C"patternUrl"%3A"https%3A%2F%2Fx.y.z%2FmultiMarkers4patts%2Ff.patt"%7D%5D%7D
```

As I said , for `https://x.y.z/learner` the scripts are included but I don't have the options and I need them

When I'm on learner.ejs page the console log in devTools has the 400 response from server for all scripts :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

How can I import these scripts and keep the options so I will be able to learn the marker area?

Comment: Hi @PiotrAdamMilewski and thank you for help but I'm afraid this is not what I need. I've read that question already but it's not what I want , the goal of that question isn't a marker area.

A marker area would look like this :

https://twitter.com/jerome_etienne/status/860549893089374208

Comment: Oh, I've quite misunderstood it then, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll put here the answer to my question.

After posting this question, I've tried to change back from EJS to HTML and see if there's any difference, still the same results.
So I chose the hard way: I've made some changes in the library, to sum it up:

I've kept the way how I access the file e.g: via /learner & without any parameters in the URL, **But I need them**, so I've moved them on the web localStorage and just used them from there on the website part and that worked.